# Cannot load `cheerio` in PhantomJS script

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, cheerio

I am using node version 4.8.1 on a Mac (homebrew install), PhantomJS version 2.1.1 and cheerio@0.22.0

Now if I require cheerio in a phantomjs script like so

```
// myscript.js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
console.log("done");
```

and run that script (with nothing else in it) with

```
$ phantomjs myscript.js
```

Then I'll get this error:

```
TypeError: Object is not a constructor 
(evaluating 'require("inherits")(Parser, require("events").EventEmitter)')

phantomjs://platform/Parser.js:124
```

I can do all sorts of things with PhantomJS. The only thing I can't is using cheerio with it.

Is there a way for me to make cheerio work within PhantomJS? Or alternatives to cheerio that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cheerio is a node.js module, but PhantomJS is not node.js. Since cheerio is "jQuery for server" you may actually use real jQuery with Phantom, including it into your target page:
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html

```
page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', 
function() {
(page.evaluate(function() {
  // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
  var $loginForm = $('form#login');
      $loginForm.find('input[name="username"]').value('phantomjs');
      $loginForm.find('input[name="password"]').value('c45p3r');
    }))
  }
);
```